# Alamofire Swift 3 extra argument in call when using ParameterEncoding

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, alamofire

I am having issues getting this line of code to work. I keep getting the error of Extra Argument in Call. When I change the encoding method I get errors like Extra argument 'Method' in call. How can I get this to work with Alamofire and swift 3.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, parameters: ["part":"snippet","maxResults":"30","key":API_KEY, "playlistId": playlist_Id], encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in

 if let jsonResult = response.result.value{

            var videosArray = [LastVideos]()

            for video in jsonResult["items"] as! NSArray{

                let lastVideo = LastVideos()

                lastVideo.title = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.title") as! String
                lastVideo._description = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.description") as! String
                lastVideo.id = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.resourceId.videoId") as! String
```

Any help is appreciated. Im 14 and pretty new to using Alamofire.
Thanks

Comment: It should be `Alamofire.request(url, method: .GET, parameters: ...`. Here is this method in the header: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Alamofire.swift#L132

Comment: Still getting the same error: Extra argument method in call.